# Sort hibernate lucene result by publication date

Tags: hibernate, search, lucene, hibernate-search

Scenario of searching news, I would like to show the latest news on top. How should I do in hibernate lucene search? It seems by default it shows earliest on top.

Well I also don't want to set a sort manually on publication date, it makes the relevance useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer here

[Hibernate Search sorting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30222490/hibernate-search-sorting)

The key point is add "SortField.FIELD_SCORE" in the sort field.